# when I run a simple code I get an error: "The file name must end with .xml"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I just started learning Kotlin using Android Studio 4.1.3.

When I am trying to run a very simple code (to just print a word) on the new Test.kt file, I get this error:

[image]

I searched on the net but I couldn't figure out what is the source of this error.
Thank you

Comment: You need to include your source code.

Comment: You can't have kotlin file under the layout folder!

Comment: @JuniaMontana I just opened a new file from "kotlin/class file". It just opened the new file in such a directory.

Comment: @Peyman please refer to the given answer. You should create .kt file under app/src/main/java. res/layout is where you will have your UI's like homepage.xml etc

Comment: @JuniaMontana Sorry, my question might be very stupid. but I don't have a app/src/main/java in my directories. when I open a new file from "File-> new->Kotlin Class/File", the android studio opens it in that "app/src/main/res/" by itself.

Comment: @Peyman I meant to say "No question is Stupid" lol sorry

Comment: @JuniaMontana  thank you very much for kind response. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Peyman since you've just started, I will give a dry run down how to build an app. Go to file -> New Project -> Empty Activity -> Fill up the form and click finish. You will be automatically navigate to the Activity. Then you will see your project structure like below:

```
app ->
      src ->
            main ->
                   java -> // this is where you will create hello.kt file. just click on the folder, create a package inside the package create .kt file -> like class Hello: Fragment (or AppCompatActivity) {... other stuff}
                   res -> // this is where you will create UI files such as hello.xml
```

Comment: Oh, that worked. I think the "app/src/main/res" was already opened and whatever new file I was creating, was opened in that directory.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a kotlin file inside of the `app/src/main/res/*` directory. It needs to go inside of `app/src/main/java/*`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just opened a new file from "kotlin/class file". It opened the new file in such a directory. Is there a way to open the new file in the app/src/main/java/ or move it to the desired directory?